# Looping sequences of animations

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i am trying to make a sequences of animations on the screen, in which one second one would be looped infinitely. I have a problem calling them properly. I tried to delete .start() from componentDidmount and perform .start(()=>this.animate2) but it messes up whole animation. I can't figure out how can i do it properly.

Thanks in advance!

To simplify the code it looks like this:

```
animate1(){Animated.sequence([...])}
animate2(){Animated.sequence([...])}
```

In the componentDidmount i call both of them:

```
componentDidMount() {
      Animated.sequence([
        this.animate1(),
        Animated.delay(3000),
        this.animate2()
      ]).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want animate2 to loop forever? What if you tried separating these animations?

```
componentDidMount() {
  Animated.sequence([
    this.animate1(),
    Animated.delay(3000),
  ]).start(() => this.animate2());
}

animate2 = () => {
//not sure what this does but you would put that logic here
//for example
  Animated.timing(
  this.state.fadeAnim,
  {
    toValue: 1,
  }
  ).start(() => this.animate2());  // recursively call this.animate2
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it this way but the problem is that then the animate2() starts animating almost immediately, not respecting the order in componentDidMount(). Moreover, after one run of the functions i get an error:undefined is not an object(evaluating 'animations[current].start')